# How to do a conditional $lookup in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, lookup

I have three collections: A,B,C.

A has a property named a, which is a ref id in B or C.

What I want to do is, look up in B first, if nothing found, then look up in C.

Something like this:

```
[
    {
        $lookup: 
        {
            from: 'B',
            localField: 'a',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'temp'
        }
    },
    { 
        $unwind: 
        {
            path: '$temp', 
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true 
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: 
        {
            if: 'temp not exist',      <! just demonstrate !>
            from: 'C',
            localField: 'a',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'temp'
        }
    },
]
```

I don't know how to implement this. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: please provide sample data for each collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think we can do conditional pipeline stages(we can do conditional operators but not stages), based on information we have while the query is running.

*if we had the information while writting the query we could generate the query dynamically and include a stage or not

But you can use `$lookup` with a pipeline, and add this filter, like if temp is empty array (meaning no join happened), to join only then.

I dont see a reason to do the unwind in the middle, make the 2 lookups and do it after.

Query

- do the first lookup
- second lookup is pipeline with filter that requires first lookup temp array to be empty
  (if you keep the unwind in the middle use this `{"$eq": [{"$type": "$temp"}, "missing"]}` instead of the empty check)
- keeps as temp, the temp or tempC depending who is not empty
- unset the tempC
- does the unwind now (join before unwind is faster i think, its less documents), also you want first to find the join members and then unwind

```js
aggregate(
[ {"$lookup": 
    {"from": "B", "localField": "a", "foreignField": "_id", "as": "temp"}},
  {"$lookup": 
    {"from": "C",
      "let": {"a": "$a", "temp": "$temp"},
      "pipeline": 
      [{"$match": 
          {"$expr": 
            {"$and": [{"$eq": ["$temp", []]}, {"$eq": ["$a", "$_id"]}]}}}],
      "as": "tempC"}},
  {"$set": {"temp": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$temp", []]}, "$tempC", "$temp"]}}},
  {"$unset": ["tempC"]},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$temp", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true}}])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. From my understanding, it will search in both B and C collections. But actually it is not necessary and may cost additional time. Do we have any solution that we can skip the second search if the first search had already returned something?

Comment: i benchmarked it, MongoDB even if you put a filter that is always false that only needs field of the collection from the pipeline(and not the other collection) you still pay like 75% cost of the lookup, MongoDB doesn't optimized, i hope it would but it doesnt. The above code does what you want, but you cant completly escape the cost of look up.